# How to debug RealmMigrationNeededException on Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

I use a realm database in my android project.

I've added a new column to my realm db which I generate out of a CSV and did the same in my entity file.

However, I now get a `RealmMigrationNeededException` if I start my app although I have uninstalled it before. So it seems like if my generated database and the entity file don't match.

I would like to know if it's possible to find out what exactly causes the exception. The stacktrace I get in Android Studio doesn't contain any clues which might help me to resolve the issue

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: de.myCompany.myApp, PID: 5270
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE flg=0x4000010 (has extras) } in de.myCompany.myApp.helper.WifiReceiver@2d683f50
     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:872)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
Caused by: io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: RealmMigration must be provided
     at io.realm.BaseRealm.migrateRealm(BaseRealm.java:589)
     at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1224)
     at io.realm.Realm.migrateRealm(Realm.java:1213)
     at io.realm.Realm.createInstance(Realm.java:237)
     at io.realm.RealmCache.createRealmOrGetFromCache(RealmCache.java:114)
     at io.realm.Realm.getInstance(Realm.java:197)
     at de.myCompany.myApp.ImageDownloadController.fillDownloadStack(ImageDownloadController.java:94)
     at de.myCompany.myApp.ImageDownloadController.<init>(ImageDownloadController.java:37)
     at de.myCompany.myApp.ImageDownloadController.getInstance(ImageDownloadController.java:42)
     at de.myCompany.myApp.helper.WifiReceiver.onReceive(WifiReceiver.java:30)
     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:862)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Is there any proper way to debug a `RealmMigrationNeededException` except for trial and error?

Comment: Try adding an empty `RealmMigration` to your `RealmConfiguration`. Then it should show you the underlying reason afterwards.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior That worked. You can post an answer if you like. Otherwise I'll do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a `RealmMigrationExceptionNeeded` error happens, Realm automatically tries to trigger any configured migration to fix it. If no such `RealmMigration` exists, you instead get another `RealmMigrationNeededException` that overrides the underlying cause.

The fix is to just provide a dummy RealmMigration to see the real error.

I can see why it can be a bit confusing, and we should probably consider throwing a better exception message that also include the underlying cause.

Comment: Yes, you should. :) Thank you for Realm too.